# Disk size in Windows for particular drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to know disk available size for particular drive say D, in GB.
I am using below wmic command,

`wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption`

but it is giving info about each drive, I want for particular drive only and that even in GB.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where ^"DeviceID^=^'D:^'^" get size^,freespace^,caption /format:Wmiclivalueformat.xsl^|find "="') do @set %%a
```

As the numbers could be pretty big and overflows the integers you can get get the free space in GB by getting a substring (be grateful that this requires only division by powers of 10 - though it's not pretty accurate as the real division should be by 1024):

```
set freespaceinGB=%freespace:~0,-10%
set freespaceinGB_MOD=%freespace:~-10,-8%
echo %freespaceinGB%,%freespaceinGB_MOD%
```

Comment: Yes..Just give me a minute

Answer (score 1):

This dual routine shows the free space on all drives.  You can use the main batch file to find the space free on a single drive.

```
@echo off
for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist %%A:\ call :bytesfree.bat %%A
pause
goto :EOF


:: Below is the batch file that returns the freespace from the letter in `%1`


@echo off
:bytesfree.bat - Salmon Trout
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%A in ('dir %1: ^| find "bytes free"') do set bytesfree="%%C"
echo Wscript.echo Formatnumber(eval(WScript.Arguments(0)/1073742268), 2, True,, False) > "%temp%\Calculate.vbs"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\Calculate.vbs" %bytesfree%') do set GBfree=%%A & del "%temp%\Calculate.vbs"
set "GBFree=                %GBFRee%"
set GBFree=%GBFRee:~-12%
echo %1 %GBfree% GB free
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Hey Thanks it works for me. It is asking for press enter to continue.. how this portion can be removed. Means it should come to command prompt directly. Also Can we have case like C drive should have 20 GB free space and E drive have 50 GB free space.If both condition are satisfied then print status as OK else Not OK with respective drive free space notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the VB script then Check this Microsoft link this might resolve your issue.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198873.aspx

You just need to copy that code in notepad and save it as .vbs format and execute the file from commandline. command will be like this. cscript filename.vbs

Answer (score 0):

I have a batch file that verifies HDD, Mem, OS and CPU arch, I ripped it a bit to fit your needs. Just set the wanted drive followed by `:`.
To convert the bytes to GB, I first trim in 1000 until the value can fit in 32bits and only then I divide in 1024. (cmd can only handle 32 bit integers).

```
@echo off setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

rem UNIT is used to convert from Bytes to GB  
rem         0 - B, 1 - KB, 2 - MB, 3 - GB

SET DRIVE="C:"

REM check all local drives for minimum space requirement 
:Local_Drives_space_check   
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in ('wmic LogicalDisk Where DeviceID^=!DRIVE! Get FreeSpace') do (
    if not "%%b"=="" (
        set /A UNIT=0
        set _tmp=%%a
        call :TRIM !_tmp! space
        echo drive !_drive:~0,1! has !space!GB free space
            )
    )
)
goto :end
REM :TRIM should get value to trim and a var name to store answer
REM examle: call :TRIM 536870912000 space
REM answer will be 512GB even though correct answer is 500GB
REM cmd.exe cannot handle numbers larger then 32bit
:TRIM
set _tmp=%1
set %2= 
set /A %2=!_tmp! >nul 2>nul
if not defined %2 (
    set _tmp=!_tmp:~0,-3!
    set /A UNIT=!UNIT!+1
    call :TRIM !_tmp! %2
    goto :eof
)
:GB
    if !UNIT! LSS 3 (
        set /A %2=!%2!/1024
        set /A UNIT=!UNIT!+1
    )
    if !UNIT! LSS 3 goto :GB
goto :eof

:end
```